# Templates for Mailchimp response emails for signup forms

Tags: html, email, templates, mailchimp

I would like to use my campaign template for response emails (template -> signup forms -> forms and response emails). How can I do that? Or how can I just edit the html of automatic opt-in and confirmation emails?

Thanks.